# $(max,+)$ matrix product with limited number of values

Tags: reference-request, matrices, multiplication

I read that there is a $\Omega(n^3)$ lower bound for $(max,+)$ matrix multiplication (with $n\times n$ matrices). This is the matrix product defined as: $(A\cdot B)_{ij}:=\max^n_{k=1}\{A_{ik}+B_{kj}\}$, for some $n\times n$ matrices $A$ and $B$. This lower bound means that the trivial algorithm is the best one.

Is there a better algorithm if we restrict the values to be in a finite set? For example, all the matrix entries are $0$ or $1$. Note that this is different from Boolean matrix product.

Any reference is welcome.

Comment: It is a matrix product over the semiring $(\Re_+\cup \{\infty\},\max,+)$. It can be seen as the classical matrix product where $+$ is replaced by $\max$ and $\times$ is replaced by $+$. Thus $(A^2)_{ij}=\max_{k=1}^n\{A_{ik}+A_{kj}\}$ .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The paper [All pairs shortest paths using bridging sets and rectangular matrix multiplication](https://arxiv.org/abs/cs/0008011) by Uri Zwick shows that the APSP problem can be solved in subcubic time, given a bound on the edge-weights. The APSP problem uses a $(\min,+)$-matrix product. Since $\max_{A} \sum_{a\in A} a = -\min_{A} -\sum_{a\in A}a = -\min_A \sum_{a\in A}-a$, we can express a $(\max,+)$-matrix product as a $(\min,+)$-matrix product and vice versa, as the paper allows edge-weights to be either positive or negative.

So this gives a subcubic algorithm for $(\max,+)$-multiplication when the values are bounded.